Why there is no [pkcs7] tag?
There is 17 questions that deals with PKCS7, but there is no pkcs7 tag.
Is there a particular reason for this, or it was just not created ?

a pure guess: All the authors didn't have enough rep to create new tags?

It's my case and so a reason for this post,

It looks like nobody yet thought about creating such a tag... We don't even have a pkcs1 tag.... I'll just tag those questions pkcs7.

Not sure if PKCS7 is a good tag since most of these question refer to PKCS7 blockcipher padding, which is only a small part of PKCS7. Perhaps it's better to have one [PKCS7-padding] tag and another for CMS.

PKCS#7 specifies the Cryptographic Message Syntax CMS. A small part of this is a padding for blockciphers, generalizing the padding from PKCS#5 to other block sizes.
Many questions mentioning PKCS#7 are about the block-cipher padding. I don't think it's useful to use the same tag for questions about the padding and CMS.
Introducing a tag for CMS seems useful, but I'd tend to name it cms not PKCS#7 to avoid confusion with the padding. I found 4 questions related to CMS.
Introducing a tag for PKCS#7 blockcipher padding is a bit dubious. I'd either keep it at the current padding, or introduce a separate blockcipher-padding, to distinguish it from the rather different RSA paddings.

Guess it makes sense to make the (now existing) pkcs7 tag a synonym of padding then?
